# how to add BatchNormalization with SWA:stochastic weights average?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am a beginner in Deepleaning and Pytorch.

I don't understand how to use BatchNormalization in using SWA.

pytorch.org says in https://pytorch.org/blog/stochastic-weight-averaging-in-pytorch/:

> Note that the SWA averages of the weights are never used to make
>   predictions during training, and so the batch normalization layers do
>   not have the activation statistics computed after you reset the
>   weights of your model with `opt.swap_swa_sgd()`

This means it's suitable for adding BatchNormalization layer after using SWA?

```py
# it means, in my idea

#for example

opt = torchcontrib.optim.SWA(base_opt)
for i in range(100):
    opt.zero_grad()
    loss_fn(model(input), target).backward()
    opt.step()
    if i > 10 and i % 5 == 0:
        opt.update_swa()
opt.swap_swa_sgd()


#save model once
torch.save(model,"swa_model.pt")

#model_load
saved_model=torch.load("swa_model.pt")

#it means adding BatchNormalization layer??
model2=saved_model
model2.add_module("Batch1",nn.BatchNorm1d(10))

# decay learning_rate more
learning_rate=0.005
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model2.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# train model again 
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    loss = train(train_loader)
    val_loss, val_acc = valid(test_loader)
```

I appreciate your replying.

following your advise,

I try to make example model adding  optimizer.bn_update()

```py
# add  optimizer.bn_update() to model

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
learning_rate=0.01

base_opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer = SWA(base_opt, swa_start=10, swa_freq=5, swa_lr=0.05)

def train(train_loader):
    #mode:train
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        #loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        running_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    optimizer.swap_swa_sgd()
    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)

    return train_loss


def valid(test_loader):

    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    #torch.no_grad
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (images, labels) in enumerate(test_loader):
            outputs = model(images)

            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            running_loss += loss.item()

            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            total += labels.size(0)

    val_loss = running_loss / len(test_loader)
    val_acc = float(correct) / total

    return val_loss, val_acc



num_epochs=30

loss_list = []
val_loss_list = []
val_acc_list = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    loss = train(train_loader)
    val_loss, val_acc = valid(test_loader)
    optimizer.bn_update(train_loader, model)
    print('epoch %d, loss: %.4f val_loss: %.4f val_acc: %.4f'
          % (epoch, loss, val_loss, val_acc))

    # logging
    loss_list.append(loss)
    val_loss_list.append(val_loss)
    val_acc_list.append(val_acc)

# optimizer.bn_updata() 
optimizer.bn_update(train_loader, model)

# go on evaluating model,,,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the documentation is telling you is that since SWA computes averages of weights but those weights aren't used for prediction during training the batch normalization layers won't see those weights. This means they haven't computed the respective statistics for them (as they were never able to) which is important because the weights are used during *actual* prediction (i.e. not during training).

**This means, they assume you have batch normalization layers in your model and want to train it using SWA.** This is (more or less) not straight-forward due to the reasons above.

One approach is given as follows:

> To compute the activation statistics you can just make a forward pass on your training data using the SWA model once the training is finished.

Or you can use their helper class:

> In the `SWA` class we provide a helper function `opt.bn_update(train_loader, model)`. It updates the activation statistics for every batch normalization layer in the model by making a forward pass on the `train_loader` data loader. You only need to call this function once in the end of training.

In case you are using Pytorch's [`DataLoader` class](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) you can simply supply the model (after training) and the training loader to the `bn_update` function which updates all batch normalization statistics for you. You only need to call this function once in the end of training.

---

Steps to proceed:

1. Train your model that includes batch normalization layers using SWA
2. After your model has *finished* training, call `opt.bn_update(train_loader, model)` using your training data and providing your *trained* model

Comment: I appreciate your replying. following your advise,i improve my code.

Comment: and,,,i don't understand which is position of bn_update() is correct.  is optimizer.bn_update() desireble every epochs?

Comment: No, the documentation states that you only need to call this _once_ after training: "You only need to call this function once in the end of training.".

Comment: thanks to you,I understand BatchNormalization in SWA.  I improved my code.

Comment: If my answer helped you (and your network actually works) I'd be happy if you accepted it as the correct answer ;)

Comment: Mr.Florian Blume,Im sorry for the late reply.

I tried to compare before and after using optimizer.bn_update() in Mnist Data.

Comment: No problem! What was the result of applying `bn_update()`? Did it work?

Comment: I think bn_update() method works successfly, thank you.

Comment: Could you accept my answer as correct then? You can do so by clicking the tick symbol next to it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to compare before and after using optimizer.bn_update() in Mnist Data.

as follows:

```
# using Mnist Data

X_train  = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
X_test   = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
X_train  = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test   = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test  /= 255

# to compare Test Data Accuracy
X_train_=X_train[0:50000]
y_train_=y_train[0:50000]
# to validate for test data
X_train_ToCompare=X_train[50000:60000]
y_train_ToCompare=y_train[50000:60000]

print(X_train_.shape)
print(y_train_.shape)
print(X_train_ToCompare.shape)
print(y_train_ToCompare.shape)
#(50000, 784)
#(50000,)
#(10000, 784)
#(10000,)

# like keras,simple MLP model 
from torch import nn
model = nn.Sequential()
model.add_module('fc1', nn.Linear(784, 1000))
model.add_module('relu1', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('fc2', nn.Linear(1000, 1000))
model.add_module('relu2', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('fc3', nn.Linear(1000, 10))
print(model)
# using GPU
model.cuda()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
learning_rate=0.01

base_opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer = SWA(base_opt, swa_start=10, swa_freq=5, swa_lr=0.05)

def train(train_loader):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        running_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    optimizer.swap_swa_sgd()
    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)

    return train_loss


def valid(test_loader):

    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (images, labels) in enumerate(test_loader):
            outputs = model(images)

            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            running_loss += loss.item()

            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            total += labels.size(0)

    val_loss = running_loss / len(test_loader)
    val_acc = float(correct) / total

    return val_loss, val_acc



num_epochs=30

loss_list = []
val_loss_list = []
val_acc_list = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    loss = train(train_loader)
    val_loss, val_acc = valid(test_loader)
    optimizer.bn_update(train_loader, model)
    print('epoch %d, loss: %.4f val_loss: %.4f val_acc: %.4f'
          % (epoch, loss, val_loss, val_acc))

    # logging
    loss_list.append(loss)
    val_loss_list.append(val_loss)
    val_acc_list.append(val_acc)
# output:
# epoch 0, loss: 0.7832 val_loss: 0.5381 val_acc: 0.8866
# ...
# epoch 29, loss: 0.0502 val_loss: 0.0758 val_acc: 0.9772

#evaluate model 

# attempt to evaluate model before optimizer.bn_update()
# using X_train_toCompare for test data
model.eval()

predicted_list=[]
for i in range(len(X_train_ToCompare)):
    temp_predicted=model(torch.cuda.FloatTensor(X_train_ToCompare[i]))
    _,y_predicted=torch.max(temp_predicte,0)
    predicted_list.append(int(y_predicted))

sum(predicted_list==y_train_ToCompare)
# test accuracy 9757/10000

#after using:optimizer.bn_update
model.train()
optimizer.bn_update(train_loader, model)

# evaluate model 
model.eval()

predicted_list_afterBatchNorm=[]
for i in range(len(X_train_ToCompare)):
    temp_predicted=model(torch.cuda.FloatTensor(X_train_ToCompare[i]))
    _,y_predicted=torch.max(temp_predicted,0)
    predicted_list_afterBatchNorm.append(int(y_predicted))

sum(predicted_list_withNorm==y_train_ToCompare)
#  test accuracy 9778/10000
```

I　don't know if this way is correct to validate...

Using optimizer.bn_update() method, I confirm test accuracy is improved ofen.
but some test accuracy is descended：I think this is because of 
simple MLP model and learning epochs are not enough.
there is need to try test more.

thank you for reply.